# Unity OnCollision() not working

Tags: unity, collision-detection

Seem to have exhausted google looking for an answer to a VERY bullet simple code that should work.

```
void onCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    print ("hit " + col.gameObject.name);
    Destroy (gameObject);
    }
```

Bullet object has the above script, SphereCollider (radius a lot bigger than object), RigidBody, not a trigger, not kinematic, is travelling slow. All checked during runtime.

When it hits a wall (Box collider), it just bounces off but no collisionEnter code is ran.

Debug console bubble is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are trying to call `onCollisionEnter()`, MonoBehaviour uses the function `OnCollisionEnter()`.

The difference is quite enormous, on the technical side of things. Being a function, the *first* letter should be a capital. By being lower case, your creating an entirely *different* function, that does not overload the original collision function your trying to call from MonoBehaviour.

To *clarify*, we are not *overloading* a method from `MonoBehaviour`, in the traditional sense. You should ***not*** use the `override` keyword, as this will report "no suitable method found to override".

Comment: I can't believe i overlooked that! Lesson learned, thanks

Comment: @herewego, its an easy mistake one has to make a few times to get into the right habits. Be sure to try it out and confirm thats your only problem, though. If it fixes it, be sure to accept the answer, so others know you found a solution.

Comment: Yeah it worked, I have to wait a few mins till it allows me to accept answer though. Thanks again

Comment: I recommend to use the `override` keyword so compiler would emit an error if the method is not overriding the super class method.

Comment: I mean, use `override void onCollisionEnter(...)` and then the compiler would give an error that there is no `onCollisionEnter` in `MonoBehaviour`. This is not dependent on the IDE, just a language feature that we can use.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati, I understand what your saying. What I mean is, `OnCollisionEnter()` is not intended to be overridden. I have just tested, now, to confirm. Using `override public void OnCollisionEnter` returns the same error as `override public void onCollisionEnter`; "no suitable method found to override".

Comment: Ah, I don't know unity, so that got me.